How would you say "There was an invasion of grasshoppers." in Latin?
In my YouTube video in Latin, I described the events that lead to the Great Chinese Famine, like this:

Ego etiam censeo quia sclopeta saepe adiuvant contra tyrannicalia imperia. Non semper, sed plurimis temporibus. Solam exceptionem quem scio est magna fames in Sina. Anno Domini milesimo nongentesimo quinquagesimo nono, imperium Sinae dixit hominibus in Sina quia debeant occidere aves quoniam aves edunt oryza. Et multae aves occisae erant et invasio orthopterarum fuit. Si plures homines tunc in Sina haberent sclopeta, probabiliter plures aves occisae essent, et fames peior esset. Sed plurimis temporibus, sclopeta adiuvant contra imperia.

Is that "invasio orthopterarum" a correct phrasing for "invasion of grasshoppers"? If not, how would you say it?

You could condense this question greatly by removing items that don't pertain to your actual question, like most of the lengthy story in the quote and the link to the video.

And I was hoping you'd have learned from your previous question that "time" isn't tempus.

I'd say " grex locustarum " "a swarm of locusts"

Orthoptera is a neuter plural, not a feminine singular. It's also obviously not a Latin word but a modern Greek-derived scientific name.

Something unrelated to the question: the word for China, Sinae is plurale tantum

Ogilvie's Horae Latinae has this to say: "Invasion = incursio, excursio, aggressio, not invasio."
But perhaps we don't really want a noun here at all when a verb will do. One possible rendering:
multis avibus occisis, magna grex gryllorum [in agros] incurrerat/invaserat.
Note: I'm not sure which tense you wanted: "occisae erant" is pluperfect, while "fuit" is perfect.
I gave the pluperfect above, but if you want the perfect: incurrit/invasit

Why gryllus, a word that mostly means cricket, rather than locusta?

@Cairnarvon I literally had no idea that locusts were grasshoppers. Locusta does seem good. I looked up gryllus in OLD and it said "a cricket or grasshopper". I don't know if one term is preferable to the other.

The sense I have is that gryllus/grillus is mainly about the noise both crickets and grasshoppers make (I agree with the view that it's onomatopoeic and not actually the same word as gryllus 'caricature', which is a loan from Greek γρύλλος) and locusta is used when talking about grasshoppers as pests, as in the plague of locusts in the Vulgate, though I can't actually back that up. Romance reflexes of grillus universally mean cricket, though.

Locusts indeed are a type of grasshopper.
